# Editing function to make a search in for loop

Tags: python, regex, match, regex-group

I got original function:

```
def getpingresults():
    iplist = dict(load_devicefile())
    cmd = "/usr/sbin/fping -C 3 -A -q {}".format(" ".join(map(str, iplist.keys())))
    exitcode, out, results = get_fping_output(cmd)

    pingresults = []
    for aline in results.split("\n"):
            print('Working on line: {0}'.format(aline))
            if aline:
                    m = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+:\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)", aline)
                    ipaddress = m.group(1)
                    rtt = (float(m.group(2)) + float(m.group(3)) + float(m.group(4))) / 3
                    if rtt == '-':
                            iplist[ipaddress] += (float(9999),)
                    elif float(rtt) > 60:
                            iplist[ipaddress] += (float(rtt),)
                    else:
                            iplist[ipaddress] += (float(rtt),)

    print(iplist)
    return iplist
```

i need to edit this thing to make sure that if in any of these m.group(2-4) variables contains symbol (-). If yes - It should to (float(9999)).

So, to make a search in `m.group(2)) + float(m.group(3)) + float(m.group(4)))` i tried to do this:

```
for rtt in m.group(range(2,5)):
                         if rtt == '-':
                            iplist[ipaddress] += (float(9999),)
                         elif float(rtt) > 60:
                            iplist[ipaddress] += (float(rtt),)
                         else:
                            iplist[ipaddress] += (float(rtt),)
```

but im getting an error on this `for rtt in m.group(range(2,5)):`

```
 File "MassPing_mod.py", line 61, in getpingresults
for rtt in m.group(range(2,5)):
```

IndexError: no such group

how to make correct for loop to match three m.groups(2-4)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is nonsense. You're trying to call `group`, which is expecting a number, with a generator. Instead use the generator on the outside and pull from that.

```
for rtt in (m.group(i) for i in range(2,5)):
```

Though if I could recommend something different, consider using tuple splat-unpacking on `m.groups` to make this a little prettier.

```
m = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+:\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)", aline)
ipaddress, *rtts = m.groups()
for rtt in rtts:
    # etc...
```